# JavaScript animation lag after several loops

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, velocity.js

I am animating these dotted lines (SVG) for a project using velocity.js.

However, after a few loops, the animation starts to lag a lot.

I have pasted the link to my animation in the codepen below.

http://codepen.io/aofaoin/pen/pbLvAb?editors=0110

```
for (i = 1; i <= 69; i++) {
    $("#gold2 .cls-" + i)
      .velocity("fadeOut", {
        delay: g2,
        duration: 800,
      })
      .velocity("fadeIn", {
        delay: 15,
        duration: 800,
      })
    g2 += 80;
  }
```

I can't use loop:true as i want to orchestrate/choreography the animation.

It would be great if anyone can tell me how can I stop the animation from lagging after a few loops. Thank you!

Comment: Seems you may want to initialise your `g1,g2,b1,b2,b3,b4` variables at the top of, the outer `for(a` loop rather than above it?

Comment: @JaromandaX hi, I tried putting it in the outer for loop. However, it didn't solve the issue of the animation lagging after the 2nd outer loop. Thanks for the suggestion though! :)

Comment: When you have issues with performance in browser, try wrapping your functions inside `setTimeout(() => { ... }, 0)`. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I suggest wrapping your `velocity` manipulation inside of `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0)`. This will prevent browser from freezes caused by a big number of sync operations you try to do.

```
  for (i = 1; i <= 69; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#gold2 .cls-" + i)
        .velocity("fadeOut", {
          delay: g2,
          duration: 800,
        })
        .velocity("fadeIn", {
          delay: 15,
          duration: 800,
        });
       g2 += 80;
     }, 0);
  }
```

If you need to do your animation with delay, add dedicated delay in `setTimeout`.

Comment: Hi @Appeiron, thanks for your suggestion! I tried it with my code. But it didn't fix the lag issue. I thought settng a dedicated delay might fix it but sadly, it couldn't work. Thanks anyway man :)